# Migrate from AWS: dynamoDB+API gateway to Google: DataStore +?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

After running my head against the limitations of the query options in dynamoDB (specifically the missing option of an SQL-like `IN` operator) I decided to move onto Google Cloud DataStore.

In my current implementation I have a simple JSON API setup in API gateway that utilizes a `integration request` with a `body mapping` to send requests onto DynamoDB as a `PutItem` request. The API is served via a custom domain and is used via JS on a website.

Now I would very much like something similar to AWS: API gateway -> Dynamodb for Google Cloud ??? -> DataStore, however I cannot figure out what would be the google equivalent, that can do the same simple creation of a public API, and how to get it setup?

Comment: Also Datastore does not have a native `IN`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in Using it carelessly may lead to exploding queries.

Comment: DynamoDB has a SQL-like IN operator. Its called CONTAINS.

Comment: As pointed by @Stu, check the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html). You can filter a set that CONTAINS a given value in Dynamo. I'd suggest to carefully read the entire Dynamo and Datastore documentation. Datastore billing can be unpredictable and reeeally expensive if you don't know what you're doing... Dynamo can also become a headache if you don't structure your data appropriately.

Comment: Sorry to say @RenatoByrro, but I do not think it's correct with CONTAINS. If I have say 3 items (records) with e.g. a NUMBER column called user_id (not key) where the records have e.g. 3434, 534543 and 234453 Then I can't query/filter those items by `user_id  CONTAINS(3434, 534543, 234453)`. CONTAINS is for searching inside inside a STRING or a SET, not for searching for multiple items. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html - So back to my original question ;-)

Comment: @Stu See above plz

Comment: Instead of `user_id CONTAINS(3434, 534543, 234453)` you need to concatenate multiple conditions, something like `user_id CONTAINS(3434) & user_id CONTAINS(534543) & user_id CONTAINS(234453)`. Wouldn't this work for you?

Comment: Hehe, or just using `user_id = 3434 OR  user_id = 234453  OR user_id = 534543` However that takes me back to scratch of my question. DynamoDB does not have an `IN` SQL-like filter/query method. So if I need to filter 100's of ID's at a time, it's impossible -> Google Data Store

Comment: This probably requires a new question as the current one is about migrating to Google. If you post the question, please link here and I will try and answer. Essentially you need CONTAINS or IN but it depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have same question DynamoDB to Google cloud however still deciding which one to use - Native mode vs Datastore mode. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) is the equivalent service provided by Google that should satisfy your requirements.